# What are the sources supported in Azure Data Share?

Tags: azure, azure-data-share

What are the sources/datasets are supported in Azure Data Share?

Does it support?

- Blob storage
- Azure Files
- Queues Storage
- Table storage
- Disk storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at step 7 [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/share-your-data) and from the [`REST API documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datashare/datasets/create#request-body), I believe currently following sources are supported:

- Azure Blob Storage
- Azure Data Lake Gen 1
- Azure Data Lake Gen 2

I would not be surprised if more data sources are supported down the road considering the service is in preview currently.